# MySQL Load Data enclosed character and field terminator on last field

Tags: mysql, file, load

I'm having a seemingly basic problem with loading data to MySQL. I'm using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/.../Contrato.txt'
INTO TABLE schema.contrato
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '/r/n' IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

Each line on the file looks like this, generated by another program:

```
|abc|;|cde|;|123|;|456|;|name|\r\n
```

When executing the load, everything seems to load properly, except the very last field. When I look at the table, the last field actually shows the '|' characters around the name. It's not the end of the world, but it's strange that it would do that. As of now, I'm fixing it by adding a ';' right before the     \r\n characters.

Is this the way it's supposed to be done?? Why would I need to add the field terminator before the line terminator in order to delete the field enclosers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can duplicate the effect on a file with a single line in it, with multiple lines I only get a single entry which has the final column entry of  "name| |abc" .

I changed '/r/n' to '\r\n' & the load worked correctly for files with a single entry & multiple entries & the surrounding | were correctly removed

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/.../Contrato.txt'
INTO TABLE schema.contrato
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

The correct MySQL escape character is backslash not forwardslash which is not treated as a special character - so your original code was looking for the 4 character sequence "forwardslash r forwardslash n" to terminate the lines

Comment: But you DID manage to replicate the issue. Is this a bug related to the end of file? To be safe, I left the additional semicolon and changed the slashes as you suggested. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It is not a bug related to end-of-file - see my edited answer. This is why your pathname to the text file worked - if you used the usual backslash path separator for Windows then you would have needed to double them up - fortunately most (not all) s/w silently sets the correct separator so you can use forwardslash as the path separator with MySQL.

Comment: I see. How come it still separated the lines, though? Is it using a default value on top of the specified string?